# How to implement form validation with Angular JS and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

At a user registration web form I validate via ajax whether a username already exists in DB. When a username already exists, the corresponding `input-text` will go `.has-error` class.

## Edit

I changed the ng-class attribute to `{'has-error':signup.userUnavaliable()}` but even though that the input is not seemly getting such class, in other words the mail input text is not getting red.

I place the directive at the wrapper as this is how the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) tell it.

**This is how my form looks like now:**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':signup.userUnavaliable()}">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="signup.mail" placeholder="e-mail" ng-change="signup.userExists(signup.mail)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-nodel="signup.password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="signup.role" value="admin"> Administrador
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="signup.unavaliable">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

**And this is my Controller:**

```
app.controller('SignUpController',function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.userUnavaliable = function() {
        
        return $scope.unavaliable
    }

    $scope.print = function(msg) {

        console.log(msg)
    }

    this.userExists = function(mail) {

        if (mail) {

            var who = $http.get("/existingUsers/"+mail)

            who.success(function(data,status, headers, config) {
                if (data.mail) {
                    $scope.unavaliable = true
                    console.log(data.mail + " ya existe en la DB")
                }
                else{
                    $scope.unavaliable = false
                }
            });

            who.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!");
            })
        }

    }

})
```

Also, I'm trying to disable the button and it's not gettin such effect, so I think my controller has any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in bootstrap validation states, if you want your label color to be changed according to the validation state of the input, you will have to apply ng-class on that.

Here is the sample code that I had written a little while. Please note that to take advantage of Angular JS validation states on form elements, you need to provide `name` to all input types.

This code would turn the input box plus label color red or green depending upon the validation state.

```
<div class="form-group" 
             ng-class="( newProfileForm.email.$dirty ? (newProfileForm.email.$valid ? 'has-success has-feedback' : 'has-error has-feedback' ) : ' ')"
             >

                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mail" ng-required='true'>    

                    <!-- Invalid Span -->           
                    <span ng-if='newProfileForm.email.$invalid && newProfileForm.email.$dirty' class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>

                    <!-- Valid Span -->
                    <span ng-if='newProfileForm.email.$valid' class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
                    <p ng-show="newProfileForm.email.$invalid && newProfileForm.email.$dirty" class="bg-danger pad">Please enter valid email.</p>
                </div>           
        </div>
```

[EDIT] Explanation for name attribute.
Angular makes use of name attribute to determine the state of the input control. So, if you have a input control with name `username`. Even your form should have a name for angular validation states.

AngularJS would use the fallowing variables to check its validation state.

`formname.username.$valid` = if username is alright according to validation rules.

`formname.username.$invalid` = if username is invalid

`formname.username.$dirty` = if user has edited the input box

`formname.username.$pristine` = if user has not edited the input box.

Angular makes use of name attribute for validaiton.

And if you want your button to be disabled depending upon the availability of the user.
Use something like

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="unavaliable">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I'm checking it right now, why is that `name` should be set?

Comment: I am explaining it in the answer.

Comment: Honestly it was something quite different. I even opened another question related only to the Angular scope, that solved the issue. Can you check it and edit your question around it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881283/why-wont-this-variable-at-angular-js-controller-is-set-to-true/23881417?noredirect=1#23881417

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':signup.userUnavaliable()}">
```

Comment: It solved the error thing, now the prob is that input is not going reddish (has-error) ...

Comment: well the problem is that the class is being appried to your from wrapper, so if  you want to apply the class in the input element you have to add the ng-class directive to your input element or just write a css rule stating  .has-error input[type=email]{ border :solid 1px red; something like that}

Comment: I'm testing now however Bootstrap docs say it should be applied to wrapper.

Comment: didn't work,tried as you suggested but got not the expected result

Comment: oh sorry forgot about boostrap. mak sure the class is set, maybe your function is not giving the right result

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about that