# Why won't this from scope variable at Angular JS controller is set to true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to code a **controller** so some inputs get disabled after changes in another one.

This is the controllre:

```
app.controller('SignUpController',function ($scope, $http) {

    this.unavaliable = true

    this.userUnavaliable = function() {

        console.log(this.unavaliable)
        return this.unavaliable
    }

    this.userExists = function(mail) {

        if (mail) {

            var who = $http.get("/existingUsers/"+mail)

            who.success(function(data,status, headers, config) {
                if (data.mail) {
                    this.unavaliable = true
                    console.log(data.mail + " ya existe en la DB")
                }
                else{
                    this.unavaliable = false
                }
            });

            who.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!");
            })
        }

    }

})
```

As my markup below shows, one input should obtain a certain class, and another one should get disabled when `unavaliable` is set to `true`. But even I can get to the `console.log()`, the variable seems to never get true.

This is my markup:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="signup.mail" placeholder="e-mail" ng-change="signup.userExists(signup.mail)" ng-class="{'has-error':signup.userUnavaliable()}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-nodel="signup.password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="signup.role" value="admin"> Administrador
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="signup.unavaliable" >Registrar</button>
</form>
```

I tried with `$scope` instead of `this` but never got it to work that way

Comment: At some point `this` is probably not what you think it is

Comment: Probably you are trying this odd approach exposed by John Papa but you needed to,set this to a var before http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/

Comment: @Dalorzo After reading that I can't really understand what I should do. Can you explain in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.controller('SignUpController',function ($scope, $http) {
var that = this;
    that.unavaliable = true;

    that.userUnavaliable = function() {  
        console.log(that.unavaliable)
        return that.unavaliable
    }

    that.userExists = function(mail) {...
```

Your issue seems to be related to JS Context; in the example above it is preserved in `that` variable. That is how it is done in [JOhn's Papa approach](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/)

Comment: You rock it! It worked. Can you explain me a bit *with apples*. It might help other learners in future